# Unregistering DLL using RegEdit by code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I work on VB/C# .net. What I create are com classed which must be registered using regasm for my particular component to work. Everytime I will have to reregiter the dll if I do any kind of development. This is fine for now.

But if I need to register with older version of dll. I will have to delete the entry manually from the registry and then re - register the dll. For this I will have to perfrom a manual search on class id in regedit and then delete. This appears to be a hectic process and sometimes it doesn't work. can anyone suggest a proper way? A batch file method will be great.

There are around 4 class id's to be searched.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just call regsvr32 to unregister the old version, then again to register the new one?

Comment: can you post the code which you already tried?

Comment: I did not use any code. I tried unregistering by manually searching and deleting from regedit.exe

Comment: how about `regasm some.dll /unregister`?

Comment: Also there will be multiple versions installed. I have to delete all the versions. if I use regasm \u only the current version get deleted. Say I have version 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 installed one after the other. now I need to register 1.1 again. \u will un register only 1.3. even if I register again with 1.1 the one active will be 1.2